# SPARQL not grouping my results properly

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have the following SPARQL query to get the list of countries with the smallest density of population per km and their presidents (leaders):

```
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?country_name ?populationdensity ?leader
WHERE {
    ?country a dbpedia-owl:Country ;
             rdfs:label ?country_name ;
             prop:populationDensityKm ?populationdensity ;
        dbpedia-owl:leader ?leader .
    FILTER (?populationdensity < 10 && langMatches(lang(?country_name), "en")) .
} 
GROUP BY ?populationdensity
ORDER BY ASC(?populationdensity)
limit 10
```

As you can see, I am grouping results by population density, yet I am getting results which include numerous population densities duplicates: [SPARQL Query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20type%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3Fpopulationdensity%20%3Fleader%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACountry%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3ApopulationDensityKm%20%3Fpopulationdensity%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aleader%20%3Fleader%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fpopulationdensity%20%3C%2010%20%26%26%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fcountry_name%29%2C%20%22en%22%29%29%20.%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fpopulationdensity%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3Fpopulationdensity%29%0D%0Alimit%2010%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)

[image]

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
I assume it has something to do with list of leaders, where for each country more than one is return.
Is there a way to limit that to 1 leader per country somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you should put all variables you use in the group by clause.
Virtuoso currently is loose in its parsing of queries and allows things it should not.
The second is you need to select just one leader, if you don't care which one then you should use SAMPLE. If you want all of them then use a [group_concat](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#aggregates) variation.

```
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?country_name ?populationdensity (sample(?leader) as ?ls)
WHERE {
    ?country a dbpedia-owl:Country ;
             rdfs:label ?country_name ;
             prop:populationDensityKm ?populationdensity ;
        dbpedia-owl:leader ?leader .
    FILTER (?populationdensity < 10 && langMatches(lang(?country_name), "en")) .
} 
GROUP BY ?country_name ?populationdensity
ORDER BY ASC(?populationdensity)
limit 10
```

If you want the current leader you need to replace the line

```
dbpedia-owl:leader ?leader .
```

With [this](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20type%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3Fpopulationdensity%20%28sample%28%3Fleader%29%20as%20%3Fls%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACountry%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3ApopulationDensityKm%20%3Fpopulationdensity%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aleader%20%3Fleader%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3AleaderTitle%2Fdbpprop%3Aincumbent%20%3Fleader%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fpopulationdensity%20%3C%2010%20%26%26%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fcountry_name%29%2C%20%22en%22%29%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3Fpopulationdensity%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3Fpopulationdensity%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20limit%2010%20)

```
dbpprop:leaderTitle/dbpprop:incumbent ?leader .
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking in terms of returning a single results. However it's not returning the proper result. For example, a current leader of Greenland is Aleqa Hammond (prime minister), not Mikaela Engell (Speaker of the Inatsisartut). So rather than a taking a first result from the leader's list is there a way to output proper leader name? I guess this will only be possible if your query not only look for leader, but also specifically for a name of person with leaderTitle :President or Prime Minister. I am going to accept your answer, but if you have time, see if that's possible.

Comment: On a single based query it would work like this, but I am not sure about how to implement it to my own query: SELECT DISTINCT ?x3 WHERE {
  ?x0 rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country.
  ?x0 rdfs:label "Argentina"@en.
  ?x0 dbpprop:leaderTitle ?x1.
  ?x1 dbpprop:incumbent ?x2.
  ?x2 rdfs:label ?x3.
}